# SUM of differences between selective rows in table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table with call records. Each call has a 'state' CALLSTART and CALLEND, and each call has a unique 'callid'. Also for each record there is a unique autoincrement 'id'. Each row has a MySQL TIMESTAMP field.

In a previous question I asked for a way to calculate the total of seconds of phone calls. This came to this SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(differences)) 
FROM
(
    SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp)))as differences 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY callid
)x
```

Now I would like to know how to do this, **only for callid's** that also have a row with the state CONNECTED.

Screenshot of table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEnUJ.jpg

Comment: Add the sql tag for broader visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(difference)
FROM (SELECT callid, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp)) as difference 
      FROM table
      GROUP BY callid
      HAVING SUM(state = 'Connected') > 0
     ) c;
```

If you only want the difference in seconds, I simplified the calculation a bit.

EDIT:  (for Mihai)

If you put in:

```
HAVING state in ('Connected')
```

Then the value of `state` comes from an arbitrary row for each `callid`.  Not *all* the rows, just an arbitrary one.  You might or might not get lucky.  As a general rule, avoid using the MySQL extension that allows "bare" columns in the `select` and `having` clauses, unless you really use the feature intentionally and carefully.

Comment: Thanks Gordon,you are a SQL machine.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Why isn't it 'COUNT(state = 'Connected')' rather then 'SUM(state = 'Connected')'. i.e does "state = 'connected' return a numeric result? I am puzzled.

Comment: @RyanVincent . . . Because `count()` counts the number of non-NULL values.  So, `count(state = 'Connected')` = `count(state <> 'Connected')` = `count(state)`.  That is, all three will count the number of non-NULL values in `state`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Thanks for reminding me about the 'here be dragons' with SQL group functions. It is a while since i have used them that intensely. I need to go and do more reading to remind myself about 'em.